# Not getting the right values when copying structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary

A buffer that holds binary chunks of data is supposed to be copied to an array of structs (each struct represents a chunk), each chunk in the buffer is 20 bytes, first 4 bytes hold the hash value, then 8 bytes for an offset info, then 8 for a size:

thats the struct definition:

```
typedef struct{
  khint_t hash; // 4                                                                                                                                                               
  long int offset_start; // 8                                                                                                                                                      
  size_t size; // 8                                                                                                                                                                
} header_offset, *offset_p;
```

and below is the code that's supposed to do whats mentioned:

```
  offset_p *offsets;
  size_t s= HEADER_OFFSET_SIZE;

  header_offset t_offsets[n_files];                                                                                       

  for (i=0; i< n_files; i++){
    memcpy(&t_offsets[i].hash, buff, sizeof(khint_t));
    buff+= sizeof(khint_t);
    memcpy(&t_offsets[i].offset_start, buff, sizeof(long int));
    buff+= sizeof(long int);
    memcpy(&t_offsets[i].size, buff, sizeof(size_t));
    buff+= sizeof(size_t);

    printf("hash read: %p\n", t_offsets[i].hash);
    printf("offset start read: %p\n", t_offsets[i].offset_start);
    printf("offset size read: %p\n", t_offsets[i].size);
  }

  memmove(offsets, t_offsets, sizeof(header_offset)*n_files);

  buff-= s*n_files;
  free(buff);                                                                                                                                                                  

  return offsets;
```

I was struggling copying the chunks directly into a header_p* so i decided to have a temporary struct array thats copied from the buffer, then gets copied to a header_p*, I'd appreciate it even more if you could provide me with a way to do it without using a temporary struct array.

The printfs print the right data, although when calling this function, the array of the pointers returned does not hold the right data, or the same data that was printed within the loop.

I'd like to know, without further code, whether its the way im using pointers that causes the array of offset_p's not hold the right values.

Comment: Have you verified that `sizeof(header_offset)` is 20? Due to padding, it could easily be 24.

Comment: that is why id use HEADER_OFFSET_SIZE when dealing with the buffer and sizeof(header_offset) when dealing with the actual structs.

Comment: Ah, good. You're aware of that. Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No memory has been allocated for `offsets`, `memmove()` does not allocate the memory for you:

<strike>header_offset* offsets = malloc(sizeof(header_offset)*n_files);</strike>

Given that your are allocating memory to be returned the use of `t_offsets` is unrequired: just populate `offsets` directly.

EDIT:

To return a `header_offset*[]` as commented by [alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk):

```
header_offset** offsets = malloc(sizeof(header_offset*) * n_files);
for (i=0; i< n_files; i++){
    *(offsets + i) = malloc(sizeof(header_offset));
    ...
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand the OP a reference to an array of pointers (to `header_offset`) shall be returned, your solution returns a reference to an array of `header_offset`.

Answer (score 4):

`offsets` is supposedly an array of *pointers*, not structs.

The memcopy will probably overwrite a large chunk of memory past the end of the memory allocated for `offsets` (allthough we can't see how much memory was allocated for it).

I'd suggest:

```
offset_p *offsets = (offset_p*)malloc(sizeof(offset_p)*n_files);
```

And then a loop

```
for (i=0; i< n_files; i++){
    offsets[i] = malloc(sizeof(header_offset));
    memcpy(&(*offsets[i]).hash, buff, sizeof(khint_t));
    buff+= sizeof(khint_t);

    memcpy(&(*offsets[i]).offset_start, buff, sizeof(long int));
    buff+= sizeof(long int);

    memcpy(&(*offsets[i]).size, buff, sizeof(size_t));
    buff+= sizeof(size_t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To return an array of pointers to `header_offset` the array itself needs to be allocated (then referenced by `offset_p *offsets;`
) as well as the memory holding the data currently held by the temporary structures. The latter then will be references by the pointers held by `offsets`.